# SQL Server count records group by 4 weeks in month and location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count total rows of 4 weeks in month and group it by location the results should be like:

```
location week1 week2 week3 week4
Floor A  10    0     3     4
Floor B  5     2     0     0
...
```

I've tried this to get a week number by given a date.

```
CASE WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 1 AND DAY(create_date) < 8 THEN 1 
WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 8 AND DAY(create_date) < 15 THEN 2
WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 15 AND DAY(create_date) < 22 THEN 3
ELSE 4 END AS WeekNumber
```

It's gives me this result:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
| id | create_by | create_date  | WeekNumber |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |    555001 | '2018-11-01' |          1 |
|  2 |    555002 | '2018-11-05' |          1 |
|  3 |    555004 | '2018-11-06' |          1 |
|  4 |    555001 | '2018-11-10' |          2 |
|  5 |    555003 | '2018-11-17' |          3 |
|  6 |    555002 | '2018-11-17' |          3 |
|  7 |    555001 | '2018-11-18' |          3 |
|  8 |    555003 | '2018-11-20' |          3 |
|  9 |    555001 | '2018-11-22' |          4 |
| 10 |    555001 | '2018-11-25' |          4 |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

My tables

tbl_user

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | location |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |   555001 | Floor A  |
|  2 |   555002 | Floor B  |
|  3 |   555003 | Floor C  |
|  4 |   555004 | Floor A  |
|  5 |   555005 | Floor C  |
+----+----------+----------+
```

tbl_list

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | create_by | create_date  |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |    555001 | '2018-11-01' |
|  2 |    555002 | '2018-11-05' |
|  3 |    555004 | '2018-11-06' |
|  4 |    555001 | '2018-11-10' |
|  5 |    555003 | '2018-11-17' |
|  6 |    555002 | '2018-11-17' |
|  7 |    555001 | '2018-11-18' |
|  8 |    555003 | '2018-11-20' |
|  9 |    555001 | '2018-11-22' |
| 10 |    555001 | '2018-11-25' |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using pivot

```
with cte as
(
select *,location,
CASE WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 1 AND DAY(create_date) < 8 THEN 1 
WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 8 AND DAY(create_date) < 15 THEN 2
WHEN DAY(create_date) >= 15 AND DAY(create_date) < 22 THEN 3
ELSE 4 END AS WeekNumber
from tbl_list a left join tbl_user b on a.create_by=b.username
)

select * from
(select * from cte
pivot 
(
count(create_by) for WeekNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) as pv)A left join 
(select location,count(username) countofUser from tbl_user group by location)B on 
A.location=B.location
```

Comment: As a CASE stops when the first TRUE condition is met (and there's no day 0), all the `... >= ...  AND` can be simply removed

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question How do I count numbers of user like Floor A has 2 users that created list data Floor B 1 user and Floor C 1

Comment: @VintageBeef, updated the answer for count user location wise - you can check

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select u.location,
       sum(case when day(l.create_date) >= 1 and day(l.create_date) < 8 then 1 else 0
           end) as week1,
       sum(case when day(l.create_date) >= 8 and day(l.create_date) < 15 then 1 else 0
           end) as week2,
       sum(case when day(l.create_date) >= 15 and day(l.create_date) < 22 then 1 else 0
           end) as week3,
       sum(case when day(l.create_date) >= 22 and day(l.create_date) < 29 then 1 else 0
           end) as week4
from tbl_list l join
     tbl_user u
     on l.create_by = u.username
group by u.location;
```

This seems much, much simpler than attempting to use `pivot`.  Subqueries are simply not needed for this logic.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the same as your by myself too.